# Why does the secondary current change direction to increase the autotransformer capacity?

Tags: transformer, autotransformer

[image: Model]

Why does the secondary current reverse direction after this connection? The primary coil acts as a passive component with a voltage drop on it and the secondary coil acts as an active source with a voltage rise on it, but after this connection, Is reverses direction.

Comment: *But after this connection, it reverses direction* - what is "it" ? The polarity of the secondary coils is depending on the direction of the windings relative to the primary.

Comment: The current shown in red (secondary current), clearly changes direction.

Comment: I guess you draw that arrow? Based on what? In any case, transformers act on AC, not DC, so you should be more specific what you mean by "current direction".

Comment: Well, based on the momentary polarity of Vp, like we commonly do duh

Comment: How does an autotransformer connection increase the power capacity?

Comment: Where did the image come from? Please label the secondary and primary currents. Why is the wiper grounded?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orPbnOJi1bk

From minute 10. It is a repetition of the same circuit. It confused me

Comment: Sorry I don't do youtube vid but I can say that if it produced that image you posted, you should ditch watching that site and find a better way to understand autotransformers. Hmm, now how could you do that I wonder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a simulation may help:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyfUcj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Voltages]

[image: Currents]

Note that the input is 340V peak (240 VRMS) and the output is 360 VRMS. The input current is 150 A peak (106 A RMS), secondary current is 100 A peak (71 A RMS), and primary current is 50 A peak (35 A RMS). So V1 supplies 25.4 kVA, while the transformer secondary supplies 8.5 kVa. The input provides 8.5 kVA through the transformer primary plus 16 kVA added to the secondary for the total of 25.4 kVA into the load.

Comment: Yeah, I understood it better after properly learning the dot convention. Thanks for the simulation as well. Still, it is weird that the power rating changes.

Comment: A 120:120 10A isolation transformer (1200 VA) can provide 240 VAC at 10A (2400 VA) when used as an autotransformer. The power is based on the current rating of the windings, and if you don't need isolation, you can add the secondary voltage to that of the primary. The current into the center tap (20A) will split with 10A into the primary and 10A through the secondary.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a transformer (auto or not) is that it works by *resisting* magnetisation of its core.  If you force a current in one winding, the transformer will reduce the magnetisation of its core by inducing an *opposing* current in the other winding.

When it cannot do that, the primary will retain full inductivity, strongly resisting changes of current (as long as the core does not saturate).  It will only reduce its resistance against current changes in the primary if it can actually *nullify* the net magnetisation with an *opposed* current in the secondary.

This principle also holds for an autotransformer.